# Win registry - Cannot delete a value using ::RegDeleteValueA() although the value exists and is accessible

Tags: windows, key, registry

In a c++ project, I'm trying to delete a value contained in a Windows Registry key. This value is named *test*, and is located under *Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompany\MyAppName*.

To delete this value, I tried the below code:

```cpp
HKEY regKey;
bool success = false;

// open key
LSTATUS ls = ::RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\MyCompany\\MyAppName", NULL, KEY_WRITE, &regKey);

if (ls == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // delete value
    ls = ::RegDeleteValueA(regKey, "test");

    if (ls == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        success = true;
}

::RegCloseKey(regKey);

return success;
```

Executing the code above, the key opening part successes, the call to `::RegOpenKeyExA()` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`. However the delete value fails, the call to `::RegDeleteValueA()` returns (2) File Not Found as error.

My app is a 64 bit app running on Windows 11, and I created myself the value I'm trying to delete, from the same app, as well as its parent keys. I certify that both the keys and the value exist in the registry, and I can see them with RegEdit.exe

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?